# How do you clear a GPU texture using metal?

Tags: ios, textures, metal

I've got a 3D texture that is only accessible to the GPU, which I'm trying to clear at the start of a frame.  I've tried setting each element to zero using a computer shader, but that's taking nearly 3ms for a 64x64x64 texture, and I'd like to use something bigger than that.

It would be great if I could do something like the clear-on-load action for color attachments, but I'm don't think that's possible in this situation.

What's the fastest way to clear the texture?

Comment: What does your compute shader look like?  Presumably you're creating the largest possible threadgroup size (usually 512 or 1024), and launching enough threadgroups to completely fill the GPU?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is by using the renderPassDesciptor's loadActions, like so:

```
MTLRenderPassDescriptor *rpdesc = [MTLRenderPassDescriptor renderPassDescriptor];
rpdesc.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0,0,0,0);
rpdesc.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;
```